# How do I install the Unity Books Lens, and how do I use it?

Tags: 11.04, unity, lenses

I [read](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/04/five-neat-unity-lenses-in-development/) that there is a [Unity Book Lens](https://launchpad.net/unity-books-lens) available. How do I install it and how do I use it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Google Books Lens](http://launchpad.net/unity-books-lens) can currently be found in a PPA by its author, and currently have a note that `These builds may have bugs, be unstable, try to eat your kitten.`

To install add the PPA `ppa:davidc3/books-lens` ([How to Add a PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them/5102#5102)) and then install unity-books-lens from the software center.

After this, you *need* to **log out and log back** (or run `unity --replace`) in for the lens to show up and work correctly.

The lens uses the shortcut <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> to show the lens.

Alternative method

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:davidc3/books-lens
>
> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install unity-lens-books

Comment: Seems to have gone for Ubuntu 12.04?